# ODE : not sure how to make it all equal to zero in part (a)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have found the first and second derivative since we required to do so

[image: Questio]

First derivative:
[image: First derivative:]

Second derivative:
[image: Second derivative]

The prof says to substitute the value or r and w at the end but I still cant make it zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When substituting into the ODE, you should get

$a x''(t) + b x'(t) + c x(t) \\= 
a \left(r^2 e^{r t} c_1 \cos (\omega t)+c_2 \sin (\omega t))+e^{r t} \left(-c_1 w^2 \cos (\omega t)-c_2 \omega^2 \sin (\omega t)\right)+2 r e^{r t} (c_2 \omega \cos (\omega t)-c_1 \omega \sin (\omega t))\right)+b \left(r e^{r t} (c_1 \cos ( \omega t)+c_2 \sin (\omega t))+e^{r t} (c_2 \omega \cos (\omega t)-c_1 \omega \sin (\omega t))\right)+c e^{r t} (c_1 \cos (\omega t)+c_2 \sin (\omega t)) \\=e^{r t} \left(\sin (\omega t) \left(-2 a c_1 r \omega+a c_2 r^2-a c_2 \omega^2-b c_1 \omega+b c_2 r+c c_2\right)+\cos (\omega t) \left(a c_1 r^2-a c_1 \omega^2+2 a c_2 r \omega+b c_1 r+b c_2 \omega+c c_1\right)\right)$

Can you get to this point?

Now, substitute

$$r = -\dfrac{b}{2a}, \omega = \dfrac{\sqrt{4 a c - b^2}}{2a} $$

After the substitution, we get

$a x''(t) + b x'(t) + c x(t) \\= e^{-\dfrac{b t}{2 a}} \left(\left(-\dfrac{c_1 \left(4 a c-b^2\right)}{4 a}-\dfrac{b^2 c_1}{4 a}+c c_1\right) \cos \left(\dfrac{ \sqrt{4 a c-b^2}t}{2 a}\right) \\ +\left(-\dfrac{c_2 \left(4 a c-b^2\right)}{4 a}-\dfrac{b^2 c_2}{4 a}+c c_2\right) \sin \left(\dfrac{\sqrt{4 a c-b^2}t}{2 a}\right)\right)$

Do you now see how each of the terms cancels to zero (just work the cosine by itself and then the sine by itself.

The final result is zero (actually verified it using that expression).

Comment: are the coefficients of sin and cos supposed to become 0? since I get left with a 'c' term in each that I cannot cancel out

Comment: ^I also cant seem to get each coefficient to zero even disregarding the c sorry :(

Comment: Yes, for each of cosine and sine, the term will be zero. I added more details after the substitution and a note for what you can do next.